# Magento 1.9 - Can't able to save data showing https issue

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is the error message after made any changes from Magento 1.9 admin panel.

> "The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an
>   insecure connection and could be read by a third party."

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED:**
Below are the steps to do:
**Login to Magento 1.9 Admin panel and follow the steps**

- System --> Configuration --> General --> Web --> Unsecure
  Make sure that the Base URL should be "https" instead of "http"

Note: Before updating the above changes please verify all of your requests are passing through https (ex: image URL's, JavaScript link and CSS links), those are under "Media & Skin directories".